# How to make a video pause when a calayer appears

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation

I am trying to make a calayer pause the video when it appears. I do not know how to go about doing this whether I add it as another calayer or animation. Here is my code when I add the calayer before exporting it. So when the animation happens I would like to have the video pause when it appears and then resume once the animation stops.

```
 let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
    titleLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
    titleLayer.string = "Dummy text"
    titleLayer.font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, size.width, size.height / 6)

    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.duration = 0
    animation.fromValue = Int(1.0)
    animation.toValue = Int(0.0)
    animation.beginTime = 5
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    titleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pause the video before you add your animation to the layer and then resume it when the animation finishes. To know when the animation finishes, you can have an object be a delegate of `animation` and then resume playback in the `animationDidStop:finished:` delegate method.

```
func showTitle() {
    // configure animation { .. }
     animation.delegate = self 
    // pause video
     titleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
}

func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    // play video
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @gravicle. One last question, How would I go about exporting this using an avexportsession so that when the quicktime move plays it shows a pause for the animation time then it resumes?

Comment: @spel you'll have to use `AVMutableComposition` for that. The code snippet in this question is doing pretty much what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887449/black-video-caanimation-and-avfoundation-avassetexportsession